# issue while using navigation bar and UITextField

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield

I am facing a weird issue.

I have three UITextField and when keyboard overlaps the screen i am moving up the screen using code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

   if(self.view.frame.size.height==568  && textField==txtVerifyPassword)
 {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x,originalCenter.y-100);
}
else if(self.view.frame.size.height==568  && textField==txtPassword)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x,originalCenter.y-20);
}
 }
```

and I am moving to original position using:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   self.view.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x,originalCenter.y);
  }
```

Original Center in DidLoad:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
  originalCenter = self.view.center;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }
```

I am adding navigation Bar Programmatically like this:

```
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
   self.navigationItem.title = @"Demo";
   UIColor *bg = [UIColor colorWithRed:9/255.0f green:161/255.0f      blue:12/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // iOS 6.1 or earlier
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = bg;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};

} else {
    // iOS 7.0 or later
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = bg;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
}
```

When I remove navigation the every thing works great.

But when i add it i am getting two issues:

1. Extra Black Space at bottom ( View doesn't go back to its original Position)
2. When I swipe up or down navigation bar hides (don't know why this happens)

Comment: you need to add height of navigation bar. or may be your navigation bar and view overlaps in design check it first.

Comment: check this property of navigation controller `@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL hidesBarsOnSwipe NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);` for bar hides.

Comment: @AshokLondhe Why my navigation bar hides when i click anywhere on screen

Comment: @sid i think you have set your view's y position to 0(y=0). check it.

Comment: Suggestion use TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView, it is very easy to use

Answer (score 2):

Just use [TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) and you are good to go. Its easy and simple to use. you can easily achieve what you are trying to achieve here.

***Usage :***

**For** use with`UITableViewController` classes, drop `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.m` and `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.h` into your project, and make your`UITableView` a`TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView` in the xib.

If you're not using a xib with your controller, i know of no easy way to make its`UITableView` a custom class: The path of least resistance is to create a xib for it.

**For non**-`UITableViewControllers`, drop the`TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m` and`TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h` source files into your project, pop a`UIScrollView` into your view controller's xib, set the scroll view's class to`TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`, and put all your controls within that scroll view.

You can also create it programmatically, without using a xib - just use the`TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` as your top-level view.